# static imports method overlap

Tags: java, import, method-signature, static-import, method-declaration

if you have a class with a static import to `java.lang.Integer` and my class also has a static method `parseInt(String)` then which method will the call `parseInt("12345")` point to?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're inside your own class it will call *your* method.
If you're outside your class (and import both classes) you must specify which class to use.

Prove: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/download/langspec-3.0.pdf $8 and $6.3 (see comments)

Comment: can you show a reference indicating it is guaranteed by the standard to be the case? It might be compiler depended...

Comment: waiting for sm1 to reply to amit

Comment: From Java Language Specification $8: The scope (§6.3) of a member (§8.2) is the entire body of the declaration of the class to which the member belongs. | From $6.3: The scope of a declaration is the region of the program within which the entity declared by the declaration can be referred to using a simple name (provided it isvvisible (§6.3.1)).

Comment: @Paranaix: Please add link to the specs and add it to your answer, and you get my +1. It is a full proven answer, in my opinion.

Comment: i think the same, but to accept it i will need the link and these details in the answer. sorry but this is for the good of other who might have the same curiosity as me

Comment: I think it still misses one point (from jls): §6.3.1 `A declaration d of a method named n shadows the declarations of any other methods named n that are in an enclosing scope at the point where d occurs throughout the scope of d.`

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
import static java.lang.Integer.parseInt;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(parseInt("12345"));
    }

    private static int parseInt(String str) {
        System.out.println("str");
        return 123;
    }
}
```

the result:

```
str
123
```

the method in you class is executed first.

Comment: can you show a reference indicating it is guaranteed by the standard to be the case? It might be compiler depended...